# Trying to understand inferred type constraints

Tags: f#, type-inference, type-constraints

The following yields

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'P has been constrained to be type 'bool'.

for the right side of the `let myValue =` expression, and

> This code is less generic than required by its annotations because the explicit type variable 'P' could not be generalized. It was constrained to be 'bool'.

for the generic `<'P>` in the `Value` method:

```
type MyTypeA<'T> (myObject : 'T) as this =
    let myValue = this.Value<bool> "SomeBooleanProperty"

    member this.Value<'P> name = typeof<'T>.GetProperty(name, typeof<'P>).GetValue(myObject, null) :?> 'P`
```

However, this compiles just fine and yields no warnings or errors:

```
type MyTypeB<'T> (myObject : 'T) as this =
    member this.Value<'P> name = typeof<'T>.GetProperty(name, typeof<'P>).GetValue(myObject, null) :?> 'P

    member this.Method<'P> name = this.Value<'P> name
```

What's going on, here?  Why, in the first example, is the method recognized in the assignment of the private value, but not as a legitimately generic method?

Comment: Simpler repro - I am thinking this might be a bug:`> type test() as this =
    let x = this.Value<bool>()
    member this.Value<'P>() = ();;` It seems like the compiler should be generalizing here but isn't for some reason

Comment: @JohnPalmer fun thing: it will as soon as you remove the `<bool>` - I agree this is either some border-cases hidden somewhere in the specs or a bug

Comment: If you make Value mutable: `let mutable myValue : bool = false` and place  `member this.myValue = this.Value<bool> "SomeBooleanProperty"` after Method, then it works. If you put it before, it gives the error. It seems to be a corner case bug, as there is no mention of generics in the spec.

Comment: To clarify: `type MyTypeA<'T> (myObject : 'T) as this =
    let mutable myValue : bool = false
    do myValue <- this.myVal2
    member this.Value<'P> name = typeof<'T>.GetProperty(name, typeof<'P>).GetValue(myObject, null) :?> 'P
    member this.myVal2 = this.Value<bool> "SomeBooleanProperty"` works, but `type MyTypeA<'T> (myObject : 'T) as this =
    let mutable myValue : bool = false
    do myValue <- this.myVal2
    member this.myVal2 = this.Value<bool> "SomeBooleanProperty"
    member this.Value<'P> name = typeof<'T>.GetProperty(name, typeof<'P>).GetValue(myObject, null) :?> 'P` does not.

Answer (score 2):

The warning `(FS0064)` is raised by a call to *CheckWarnIfRigid* function inside *SolveTyparEqualsTyp* fun from *ConstraintSolver.fs*.
After the warning is raised, *SolveTyparEqualsTyp* will continue (since there is no error so far) to solve type constraints. 
The comment of *SolveTyparEqualsTyp* is :

```
/// Add the constraint "ty1 = ty" to the constraint problem, where ty1 is a type variable. 
/// Propagate all effects of adding this constraint, e.g. to solve other variables
```

This leads to error FS0663 for member `Value` definition in OP's example. Followed by error FS0660.
For some reason I ignore, some propagation occurs.

Maybe type inference is too aggressively performed.
@jpe and other comments below OP's question contain more interesting clues.